# Why was n't kqueue socket polling mechanism not implemented in Linux?

Tags: linux, socket

Linux has epoll for socket polling mechanism. kqueue seems to be better than epoll. Why did linux went with epoll rather than kqueue? I read about libkqueue. But that is implemented in user space and doesn't seem to be as efficient as a native kqueue implementation.